# Could not determine a MetaTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple application with FormView and SQLDataSource. When I check "Enable dynamic data support" I get following error:

> ```
> Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for
> ```
>
> the data source 'SqlDataSource1' and
>   one could not be inferred from the
>   request URL. Make sure that the table
>   is mapped to the dats source, or that
>   the data source is configured with a
>   valid context type and table name, or
>   that the request is part of a
>   registered DynamicDataRoute.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing.  I've never see this error before, and especially don't know what it means as far as DynamicDataRoute goes.  I'm not using one, as far as I know, and more over I didn't know it needed one.

Answer (score 92):

For me, it turns out that in my grid view, the columns were bound as an "asp:DynamicField", not as a "asp:BoundField"

ie

changing my columns from something like so:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:DynamicField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
</Columns>
```

to this:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
</Columns>
```

fixed it ;-)

Comment: I just hit this myself. Somehow, when I went to add a column I wound up choosing the column name I wanted from the "DynamicField" list instead of the "BoundField" list. Thanks for the easy fix! +1

Comment: This also fixed the same problem for me - but still, why were those fields turning up as "dynamicfield" in the first place?  I saw nothing in the grid view or data source properties that related to this!

Comment: I had the same issue as Mark Allen. Thanks, Brad.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use Dynamic Data you need to add a Data Model to your project, either in the form of LINQ to SQL or an Entity Framework data model.

Exact details on how to do this as an example is available on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488549.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I changed the columns to BoundField and it worked