# Dynamically binding datasource to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I am getting an error for this c# code

```
if (radioAll.Checked)
{
       SqlDataSource DataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
       DataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2";
       this.Page.Controls.Add(DataSource2);
       DataSource2.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SEP_Project_NewConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
       DataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT courseNo,title from Course";
       gridview_modules.DataSource = DataSource2;
       gridview_modules.DataBind();
}
```

The error is as follows
[image]

The connection string is ok. How to fix this error?

Comment: Since I'm at work right now, I can't see the image. Can you please post the error as a text?

Comment: Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for the data source '' and one could not be inferred from the request URL. Make sure that the table is mapped to the data source, or that the data source is configured with a valid context type and table name, or that the request is part of a registered DynamicDataRoute.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797593/could-not-determine-a-metatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the column fields of gridview

Earlier it was like this,

```
<Columns>
  <asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Course No" />
  <asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Title" />
</Columns>
```

then I changed like this,

```
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="courseNo" HeaderText="Course No" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select something from your `SqlDataSource`

```
gridview_modules.DataSource = DataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
gridview_modules.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I changed the columns to BoundField and it worked