# Why is DynamicData not working on new 2012 Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an ASP.Net website that uses DynamicData controls that works on it's current server and locally, but any page with dynamic controls fails on the new 2012 server i'm setting up.  Everything is pretty much identical from an application perspective.

Error:Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: Could not determine a MetaTable. A MetaTable could not be determined for the data source '' and one could not be inferred from the request URL. Make sure that the table is mapped to the data source, or that the data source is configured with a valid context type and table name, or that the request is part of a registered DynamicDataRoute.

Is there a missing config, feature, or role missing possibly?

Comment: I should also add that the rest of the site that doesnt use dynamic data controls works just fine and it is using the same dbml files as the dynamic controls.  I suspect that possibly the Global.asax isn't firing, therefore the routes arent registering.  However, deleting or recreating the global didnt help.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797593/could-not-determine-a-metatable

Comment: Unfortunately not related, the Dynamic controls were used on purpose and are fully functional on old server and local dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the app pool was not configured correctly.  It needed to be set to .Net 2.0 - integrated pipeline.