# Binding ADO DataReader to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado, mysqldatareader

Trying to bind the data that I recover from ADO query, I am getting the same error after trying different approach (usaing dataTable, DataView,...). The last one I used is the next:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from productos");
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

Another approach I used was:

```
MySqlConnection Com = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
Com.Open();
cmd.Connection = Com;
Datos = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(Datos);
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

The error returned in all cases is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot determine table from data
>   source. Use the MetaTable.MapTable method to establish an association
>   between a data source and a MetaTable instance.'

Comment: You get this error while loading data table from data reader or while data binding to grid view? Put breakpoint on line this.GridView1.DataSource and check the data in do object.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood. I forgot it. All the times the problem are raising in data.bind()

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797593/could-not-determine-a-metatable

Comment: @paparazzo it works... Thanks... :)